# Regex How to match ONLY File name prefix and extension ignoring the numbers in the middle in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been trying to match only specific prefix and it's extension in a filename but with no luck.
Example:

BX-ST123456.mxf ==> I need to match only BX-ST and .mxf

BX-SR123456.mxf ==> this shouldn't be a match

BXL-ST123456.mxf ==> this shouldn't be a match

so basically the match should happen only if it finds the string of BX-ST and .mxf without restricting the length of numbers in the middle (ignore them) they could be 0-9 in any random.

Example:

BX-ST0.mxf ==> should be a match

BX-ST01.mxf ==> should also be a match and so on.

appreciate your help everyone

Comment: `/^BX-ST\d+\.mxf$/`

Comment: Thanks Amadan. That worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
BX-ST\d+.mxf
```

You could also add `^` in the beginning and `$` at the end like this

`^BX-ST\d+.mxf$`

A good site to try your Regex is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Thanks Hesham that was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: @AhmedFawzi if that was what you were looking for, then please pick this as the right answer and help the community.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice class called `File` that can help you. Such that:

```
 File.fnmatch?('**BX-ST*.mxf','path/to/file/BX-ST123456.mxf')
 #=> true
```

Here the pattern is a glob pattern not a regex and simply says match directory recursively `'**'`, filename starts with `"BX-ST"` and ends with `".mxf"`.

Additionally you could go with

```
 File.extname(YOUR_FILE) == '.mxf' && File.basename(YOUR_FILE)[0,5] == 'BX-ST'
```

Here we check that the extension is `".mxf"` and that the basename's first 5 characters are `"BX-ST"`